# jQuery automatically updated value on view when button clicked

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I was create like button with current value on database and when the button has been clicked the value must be automatically updated on the view.
Currently, the value was successfully updated on database, but not automatically updated on view.

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#like').on('click', function(e){
            var id = '{{$news->id}}';
            $.get('{{ url('view/like')}}/'+id, function(data){
                console.log(id);
                console.log(data);
                $('#like_data').empty();
                $.each(data, function(index, element){
                    $('#like_data').append("<p>"+this.like+"</p>");
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function like($id){

    $news = News::find($id);

    $news->like += 1;
    $news->save();

    return $news;
}
```

Comment: Can You please describe what is the problem? What errors You get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `JSON` response from your controller. Like this

```
public function like($id){

    $news = News::find($id);

    $news->like += 1;
    $news->save();

    return response()->json([$news], 200);
}
```

you don't need to use `$.each()` for this response because you send only single object response. Just simply write this code:

```
$('#like_data').html("<p>"+data.like+"</p>");
```

if you want to use `each` just simply write:

```
 $.each(data, function (index, element) {
      $("#like_data").append("<p>" + element.like + "</p>");
 });
```

Comment: Hi, its working show single object.
but the value still say "undefined", what's mean undefined ? can you please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#like').on('click', function(e){
            var id = '{{$news->id}}';
            $.get('{{ url('view/like')}}/'+id, function(data){
                console.log(id);
                console.log(data);
                $('#like_data').empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                 $("#like_data").append("<p>" + element.like + "</p>");
              });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```